# How to expand a UICollectionView cell to the width of the screen upon selection?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to replicate how the eBay iOS apps displays its images and allows users to expand each image larger.

Here's how it works:

[image]

eBay uses a `UICollectionView` to display a list of images. When the user selects a cell, the cell expands with some buttons in the top. When the X is selected, the cell collapses back to original size.

How can I achieve something similar to this?

I've looked at questions [UICollectionView Enlarge cell on selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478329/uicollectionview-enlarge-cell-on-selection) and [Expanding UICollectionView and its cell when tapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38115217/expanding-uicollectionview-and-its-cell-when-tapped) and tried implementing it with my own ideas.

One of the problems is I have AutoLayout design, and it's making this quite difficult.

Here's my storyboard:

[image]

I've tried this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

    cell?.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: cell!)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: [], animations: ({

        self.structureImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 667)
        collectionView.frame = self.structureImageView.bounds
        cell?.frame = collectionView.bounds

        self.separatorView.frame.origin.y = 667
        self.structureInfoView.frame.origin.y = 667

    }), completion: nil)

    test = true
    collectionView.reloadData()

}

var test = false

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt  indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    if test == true
    {
        return CGSize(width: 375, height: 667)
    }
    return CGSize(width: cellWidth!, height: cellHeight!)
}
```

And the result:

[image]

Any assistance would greatly help!

Comment: Well it doesn't expand UICollectionView Cell, but it popup another controller as modal with custom transition. You might need [this] (https://github.com/michaelhenry/MHFacebookImageViewer)

Comment: Use this https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow if you have multiple images.

Comment: As @iphonic mentioned, I also think that it's not expanding the cell. It's just a modal view controller with a custom transition. It will be easier if you do it that way in your case. I'm not saying that it's not possible to do it with the cell... but it will be a lot more difficult...

Comment: Hi @Pangu i tried to provide you a solution in below some steps, have a look into this and let me know if you want to do it in that way. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Following below steps you can achieve this:

Lets say you have two ViewControllers `FirstViewController` where you have image at top and `FullImageVC` where you have image at centre.

1. Write code to Detect Tap or Place a UIButton over you initial image (Top one).
2. On action of that UIButton or Tap on image action write a logic to modal present a ViewController FullImageVC without animation.
3. On `viewWillAppear:` of `FullImageVC` you need to write logic for two things:

**First**

Place an image on top of `FullImageVC` as similar as you have placed it in a `FirstViewController` and pass same image you tapped on `FirstViewController`, and write logic to animate it from top to centre.

**Second**

As soon as animation completed show your `CollectionView` which will have all the images and show the selected one.

4.Place cross button and write its action to dismiss `FullImageVC`.